# What was the proper way to flag this answer?

Tags: discussion, first-post-review

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/15098372) answer in the First Posts Review Queue. Obviously, it was bad, so I went to flag it. (It's since been deleted, but it said something about praising some dude because he would save us from the 2048 Gods).

My question is, should this be flagged as spam? The description for spam says:

> Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation.

That's not quite the case here (unless I'm mistaken), so I chose Not an Answer, which is technically true.

Which is the "better" flag that I should have used for something like this?

Comment: So given that you know the post clearly doesn't meet the criteria for spam, and clearly does meet the criteria for Not An Answer, why ask the question?

Comment: I thought that it _might_ qualify for spam.

Comment: So you think it might be promoting a product or service?  What product or service might it be promoting?

Comment: See, that's where my question is. The answer was "promoting" (loosely termed) a guy who would save us from "the gods of 2048".

Comment: So what is the *product or service* being promoted?

Comment: I guess that is the answer to my question.

Comment: For those who don't know: [2048 is a very addicting game](http://2048game.com), which might be considered a product or service being promoted by the answer.

Comment: Tried that link, @Tiny. Can confirm it is very addicting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you see a troll post like this (and it's not spam), the best option is to flag as "rude or abusive", as it is abuse of the system. When 6 users flag a post as rude or abusive, the post is automatically deleted.

See [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/347499)